# PHP/file_get_image/finfo: Checking file validity and type remotely

Tags: php, upload, file-get-contents

I am trying to check the size and validity of files prior to placing them on my server.  Ideally, I'd like to do this remotely before uploading but as a fallback may do after upload to my server.

I came across the following suggested technique for doing this using file_get_info.  The reference does not specify whether it works with an url or just a local file path so I have tried both but neither is working.  Here is code:

where

```
$file = "/path/to/file";


$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);  
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($file));  // e.g. gives "image/jpeg"
echo $mime_type;
```

The error I am receiving is  Class 'finfo' not found

From reading documentaion on finfo on php.net, sounds like there can be some complicated environmental settings issues...but this is unfamiliar territory for me.

Can anyone suggest fix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you're on windows you probably need to uncomment the extension in your php.ini

Comment: Which version of php are you using? You can check it by: "echo phpversion();" You need to have at least 5.3 and extension enabled in php.ini

Comment: Running 5.2.17. Do you know if there is a fallback alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when the extension fileinfo.so or php_fileinfo.dll has been commented in your php.ini file (depending on your platform version). Remove the semi colon and restart XAMPP server to see the changes